# Power of an element in cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $\zeta$ be a $p^d$ primitive root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, $F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, and $D$ be the discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.

We can show that $D = \pm p^j$ for some $j$ and that $(p)$ totally ramifies in $\mathcal{O}_F$.

How can I show there is some positive integer $k$ so that
$(1 - \zeta)^{k}=D \beta$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $\Phi_p(x^{p^{d-1}})$ where $\Phi_p(x) = x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1.$ Let $S$ denote the set of primitive $p^d$th roots of unity, i.e. the roots of $\Phi_p(x^{p^{d-1}})$. Then we see that $$\prod_{\omega \in S} (1-\omega) = \Phi_p(1) = p.$$ But $S$ is a set of Galois conjugates, and so each term in the product has the same valuation at the unique prime above $p$, and valuation zero elsewhere. We conclude that $1-\omega$ is an *integral unit* multiple of $1-\zeta$ for each $\omega \in S$. So there is some unit $u$ for which $u(1-\zeta)^{|S|} = p$.

The more general underlying fact is that if $L = K[x]/f(x)$ is a Galois extension of local fields and $f$ is Eisenstein with root $\pi$, then $L/K$ is totally ramified with uniformizer $\pi$. In the above situation, the Eisenstein polynomial in question is $\Phi_p((1-x)^{p^{d-1}})$.